# How to reduce duplicated SQL statement on the stored procedure when draft the query data

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I would like to write the SQL statement as below to query the data when different input variables in stored procedure for MySQL/MariaDB:

```sql
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_WalletTransfer_GetWalletTransfers(IN IN_TypeCode smallint(6),IN IN_TransferStatusCode smallint(6), IN IN_PageIndex int, IN IN_PageCount int)
BEGIN
  DECLARE offsetValue INT;
  SET offsetValue = IN_PageCount*IN_PageIndex;
  IF IN_TypeCode = -1 AND IN_TransferStatusCode = -1 THEN
    SELECT
      Id, RefNo, TypeCode, TransferStatusCode, DateCreated, DateUpdated, MemberCode, MemberId, Amount, Memo
    FROM WalletTransfer
    ORDER BY DateCreated DESC
    LIMIT IN_PageCount OFFSET offsetValue;
  ELSEIF IN_TypeCode >0 AND IN_TransferStatusCode = -1 THEN
    SELECT
      Id, RefNo, TypeCode, TransferStatusCode, DateCreated, DateUpdated, MemberCode, MemberId, Amount, Memo
    FROM WalletTransfer
    WHERE TypeCode = IN_TypeCode
    ORDER BY DateCreated DESC
    LIMIT IN_PageCount OFFSET offsetValue;
  ELSEIF IN_TypeCode = -1 AND IN_TransferStatusCode > 0 THEN
    SELECT
      Id, RefNo, TypeCode, TransferStatusCode, DateCreated, DateUpdated, MemberCode, MemberId, Amount, Memo
    FROM WalletTransfer
    WHERE TransferStatusCode = IN_TransferStatusCode
    ORDER BY DateCreated DESC
    LIMIT IN_PageCount OFFSET offsetValue;
  ELSE
    SELECT
      Id, RefNo, TypeCode, TransferStatusCode, DateCreated, DateUpdated, MemberCode, MemberId, Amount, Memo
    FROM WalletTransfer
    WHERE TypeCode = IN_TypeCode AND TransferStatusCode = IN_TransferStatusCode
    ORDER BY DateCreated DESC
    LIMIT IN_PageCount OFFSET offsetValue;
  END IF;
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

As you can see, a lot of duplicated statement in the script. I would like to know the best way(from real practices) to draft the correct SQL statement to remove the duplicated part and keep the script clean.

How can I do? Any hints please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, I would do something like this....

```
SELECT Id, RefNo, TypeCode, TransferStatusCode, DateCreated, DateUpdated, MemberCode, MemberId, Amount, Memo
FROM WalletTransfer
WHERE (IN_TypeCode= -1 OR TypeCode = IN_TypeCode)
  AND (IN_TransferStatusCode= -1 OR TransferStatusCode = IN_TransferStatusCode)
ORDER BY DateCreated DESC
LIMIT IN_PageCount OFFSET offsetValue;
```

...**but** this might make the query much much slower; MySQL typically can't take advantage of indexes when OR conditions are involved. I personally have not noticed severe performance hits, but have generally only used this technique on "lighter" queries (MySQL might optimize out the conditions that would interfere with index use, since the -1 comparisons are essentially one time evaluations that can be determined before the query is executed in full.) This is just something to keep in mind when doing this kind of thing.

*Side note: I think there might be some weird gaps in the logic when the IN_TypeCode and IN_TransferStatusCode values are 0; `<= 0` might be a better  condition than `= -1`*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I knew this statement can use `OR` to composed in one line. But just like you said, it has some side effect from performance perfective.
And for input parameters initial from -1 because of the program set -1 as expected value for knowing condition and 0 as the default value for the value-typed in most OOP language in `INT` type. But I will try to take your advise to adjust to <=0 for better understanding on reading. Thanks.

Comment: @BlackieTsai - Well, your 4 `SELECTs` would need 4 different composite indexes to be efficient.